# Parsing function calls with optional parentheses

Tags: parsing, yacc

I'm stuck on how to write my grammar such that parentheses in function calls are optional (like in Ruby).

Here's (a stripped-down version of) the grammar I have now.

```
expr:
    '-' expr
  | expr '+' application
  | application

application:
    primary arg_list
  | primary '(' arg_list ')'
  | primary '(' ')'
  | primary

arg_list:
    application
  | application ',' arg_list

primary:
    IDENT
  | '(' expr ')'
```

An expression like `f a, b` should be parsed as `App(f, [a, b])`. `f f a, b` should be `App(f, App(f, [a, b]))`.

I've never been able to get the latter to parse without shift/reduce conflicts. Any ideas on how to structure the grammar such that we can have arbitrarily-nested operators and applications like `(f f c + a) + b`, without conflicts?